# Do electrons need specific energies to excite electrons

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electrons

Photons need specific energy levels, equal to the difference between two energy levels to excite an electron in an atom. Is this the same case with electrons that collide with atoms?

Comment: In short: yes. The energy needed to excite an electron is independent of the manner of excitation, be it the absorption of a photon or the absorption of (part of) another electron's kinetic energy (which can be thought of as being transferred by means of a virtual photon).

Comment: I ask because I am doing an A level Physics paper which is saying that an electron collides with an atom, excites one of the electrons, and the KE of the electron before is 9eV and after the collision it is 1eV. This just seemed counter to what I learnt about colliding photons needing energies equal to the differences between the discrete energy levels of the atom. If it is the same case with electrons, wouldn't all of the electrons KE have to be absorbed?

Comment: Nope, the important difference is this: in the case of the photon, the photon is *absorbed* (remember that a photon is really just a packet of energy). Contrarily, in the case of the electron, the 'free' electron and the bound one interact and due to this interaction the 'free' one loses *some* energy while the bound one gains *some* energy (ideally the same amount that was lost by the 'free' one). Because the 'free' electron can have any continuous amount of KE, it only needs *at least* the amount necessary to excite the bound electron in order to actually excite it.

Comment: @Wouter `remember that a photon is really just a packet of energy` - this is not true, a photon is a full-fledged particle. It's only that its only interaction vertex absorbs photon - a purely electromagnetic fact. And there could be another photon emitted immediately, as in the scattering of light on a free electron, or in the propagadion of light through refracting media. Why atoms are not involved in such processes, that has something to do with selection rules.

Comment: @firtree I agree it's usually considered a valid elementary particle. But considering some of the possible problems with the photon as an elementary particle (e.g. Lorentzinvariance: different observers don't necessarily agree on the number of photons; one manifestation of this is the [Unruh effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unruh_effect)), I went back to the original (Einstein) interpretation of the photon as a packet of energy being transferred from the EM field to the particle, which is the important aspect in this story anyway.

Comment: @Wouter These problems are not at all specific to the photons. They are the essential features of the QFT itself and they would accompany any quamtum particles (taking into account the production threshold). That's the world we live in, there's no way to escape from that shutting your eyes and saying it's just photons that are special. The Einstein's interpretation is well-known as incomplete and you should assume the full QFT interpretation.

Comment: @firtree I know the number of particles isn't necessarily fixed in QFT, but I had a discussion with my professor of QFT about the 'existence' of photons as actual elementary particles and he told me about this feature that evidently concerned photons only. In any case, there are problems with QFT in general, so I definitely won't just blindly accept it as reality. (I'm not saying I want to disregard it entirely, that would just be idiotic, just remain critical at all times) However, my professor was unclear about the rigour of his claim, so perhaps it's more philosophy than physics.

Comment: @Wouter Either you got him wrong or he made a mistake. These features concern all QFT particles. It's just that the photon is the only free particle with zero production threshold (disregarding neutrinos, gluons and gravitons), and the most physically-realistic consideration addresses the low-energy case, hense only photons are _usually_ mentioned. But for the extremely large accelerations (of an order $m_e$ and more), or for the last moments of the evaporating black hole, the non-zero threshold would be exceeded all the same, and you would observe other particles showing the same behavior.

Comment: @Wouter And that doesn't have anything to do with the '
problems with QFT in general'. The QFT is shown to be rigorous in this domain, which is known as the tree-level, or more generally, the low-loop level of the perturbation theory.

Comment: @firtree Quite possibly. If this is indeed the case, I stand corrected. By the way, I wasn't referring to this particular issue when I said I won't blindly accept QFT as reality. The theory as a whole is unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 2):

Energy and momentum has to be conserved. That the electron / photon has to have enough energy for the excitation is obvious. What is interesting is what happens when they have too much energy.

For radiative transitions between bound states the orbital anuglar momentum has to change by 1. This means that the photon has to be absorbed which in turns means that the photon has to have exactly the right energy (otherwise the extra energy has nowhere to go). For transitions to unbound states (so atom is oxidized) this is no longer true. A photon with 9 eV energy could very well give rise to an oxidised atom and an 1 eV photon.

Electrons can take away (and give) momentum easier so they only need enough energy for the transition. Since the electron is not absorbed it can take away any extra energy if it has too much.